# How do you Set Custom Time in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, time, date, timezone

I want to set a custom time in ubuntu 14.04

lets say : 8 OCT 2010 18:00:00

```
wrkstn@wrkstn-VirtualBox:~$ sudo date --set="8 OCT 2006 18:00:00"
Sun Oct  8 18:00:00 PETST 2006
wrkstn@wrkstn-VirtualBox:~$ date
Fri Sep  2 01:21:51 PETT 2016
wrkstn@wrkstn-VirtualBox:~$
```

But i am not able to set custom date with Date command.
Please Tell me how can i accomplish this.

Comment: But what is this command line output from then?

Comment: Reproducing this on my 16.04, the time does not change there either this way... I wonder how this is meant to work.

Comment: Does [this help](http://superuser.com/a/984016)?

Comment: Btw, that question should be migrated here.

Comment: @luchonacho There's no need to migrate that question, Ubuntu is on-topic on Super User as well. And it would be a duplicate of this one (or rather the other way round).

Comment: Does that mean that answer can be posted here, without SE rules infringements? (It seems so)

Comment: You should not really directly copy-paste the answer (which would be acceptable if it is from another site and you add a reference link though), but writing your own answer based on what you learned there is of course okay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have set up your computer to automatically synchronize time with an internet time server via NTP (which is the default), you can not edit the system time manually, because `ntpd` will immediately synchronize it with the internet clock again.

To set the system time and date manually, disable NTP:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp false
```

Then you can persistently change the time and date, like this:

```
sudo date -s "2010-1-1 13:00"
```

If you want automatic internet time synchronization enabled again, run this:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
```

Comment: no, again year is always set to 2016

Comment: Not here. What was your exact date string, maybe that one was badly formatted?

Comment: sudo date -s "2010-1-1 13:00" putting this string

Comment: This correctly sets the full date, including the year, once NTP is disabled. I can't reproduce your problem. Would you mind just trying aain?

Comment: also stopping /etc/init.d/hwclock.sh help. Have to add in rc.local. Please add it on the question.

Comment: A word of warning. All sorts of unintended consequences will arise if you set your clock way off real time (as in years). Things like expire scripts will start deleting things, calendar notifications for thousands of events you missed will show up. You might want to do this in a vm.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your Ubuntu runs in VirtualBox from your machine name. In this case, VirtualBox manages the guest time and adjusts it to match host time by default. You can disable this behavior using the command:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
```

Source: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#disabletimesync

Comment: No nothing happened with this command.