# Unable to change date and time settings in Ubuntu 16.04 using command line

Tags: command-line, 16.04, time

I have tried below commands to change date and time but these are not updating date and time.

```
sudo date --set="2015-09-30 10:05:59.990"
sudo date --set="Tue 30 May 2017 15:00:00"

sudo hwclock --systohc
```

Kindly provide valid commands for changing date and time

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/819601/how-do-you-set-custom-time-in-ubuntu?

Answer (score 27):

You can use `timedatectl`, it does all the necessary things for you itself.

First make sure NTP is not enabled:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp 0
```

then set the time:

```
sudo timedatectl set-time "2017-05-30 18:17:16"
```

make sure your timezone is correct too, e.g:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Paris
```

and also use UTC if you are using localtime:

```
sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
```

Comment: the sudo timedatectl set-ntp 0 helps me